# How does Netflix detect proxies?

Tags: netflix

Netflix has announced that it will block access to it's US service via proxies.

http://www.stuff.co.nz/technology/75920775/netflix-shutting-off-proxy-access-to-us-version

How can they do this reliably? What is it about proxy traffic that will make it look different from non-proxy traffic?

Comment: They can check the headers, cross-check ips that are known proxies and probably a few other ways as well. For example:  X-Forwarded-For would contain the IP address...

Comment: It's also **not about** the look rather it's about content that is being accessed outside of the region that should be blocked region by region.

Comment: Will this mean your content will remain the same when traveling? I.e. locked to your account's country (likely credit card's country)

Comment: Currently my proxy is still working, will wait and see

Comment: I live in Germany and have a (very new) static IP address. I get the message I should turn off my unblocker even while I don't have one enabled. I think that means they are just blacklisting IPs and I had bad luck :/

Comment: Seems they are now blocking the CDN so can browse but when playing I get errors `tvp-811` or on iOS `139 NoCDN`

Comment: They have updated which error is returned: `aip-703` `You seem to be using an unblocker or proxy. Please turn off any of these services and try again. For more help, visit netflix.com/proxy`

Answer (score 3):

I used to watch Netflix USA on my Android device, using a VPN application. But Recently, Netflix apparently blocked this technique. In fact, when I try to play a movie, a message is popped, inviting me to unable proxies unblocker.

What I have done is just switch my Android device language to be `English US` and by magic it works like before.

I think you can use the same work around on your browser by changing Locales to be the same as those of your proxy.

To conclude, I don't think Netflix is using a blacklist of DNS/Proxy IPs. They have just added some Locale checks

Answer (score 3):

Seems netflix are blanket blocking the IP address ranges of common hosting providers (AWS)

I suspect that the authorisation sent to the CDN network may include the IP the authorisation was requested from. So if the you browse from one country then all of a sudden appear to request streaming from another country you get blocked by the CDN (`tvp-811` or on iOS `139 NoCDN`).

And then your account may get tagged, but I know nothing of that.

I don't believe netflix rely on seeing an `X-Forwarded-For` header and I'm not aware of legitimate travelers being affected.

This project seems to be tracking the situation: https://github.com/ab77/netflix-proxy and they resort to proxying the CDN traffic (like a traditional VPN)